# Is there any alternate to session.getAttribute() in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2

I want to know any alternate to session.getAttribute in jsp. I have used many session variables in my jsp, but I think it is prone to XSS attack.

How to avoid this problem?

I'm using struts2 as my web application framework.

Any help would be appreciated.

I want to avoid session.getAttribute() to prevent from XSS attack.

Comment: Use expression language (EL)

Comment: you can using jstl

Comment: But I have set session variables in class level using httpSession. By el or jstl is it possile to get session values? Is there any way to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: You've already gotten two answers; what else are you looking for? What are you putting in session that would open up an XSS attack? How are you sanitizing your inputs? How are you sanitizing your outputs?

Comment: combination of EL and JSTL can sanitize the input.
`<c:out value="${sessionScope.variable}"></c:out>`

or 

`${fn:escapeXml(sessionScope.variable)}`